# My sql Select query where condition is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables sale and receipt ,table structure is give below.

**sale table**

```
id   total sale_type     cust_id

1    100    credit         10

2    200    payment        9
```

**receipt**

```
id  net_mount   payment_type  cust_id

1    50         CDM           10

2    150       Hand Over       9
```

My problem is when i give sale_type in where condition i got
   matched data from sale table and  also the data from receipt table,
   when sale_type is give i want only the matched value of sale table .
   same situation in the case of payment_type.

**Code**

```
 <?php
 $where='where 1';
 $where2='where 1';
if($sale_type<>'')
 {
  $where.=" and sale.sale_type='$sale_type'";

 } 
 if($deposited_type<>'')
 {
 $where2.=" and receipt.deposited_type='$deposited_type'";

}

if($cust_name<>'' || $cust_id<>'')
              {
            $where.=" and (sale.cust_id='$cust_name' or sale.cust_id='$cust_id')";
           $where2.=" and (receipt.cust_id='$cust_name' 
           or receipt.cust_id='$cust_id')";
              }

select total, net_amount from (select total, null as net_amount,
2 as sort_col from    sale  $where union
all select  
null as total, net_amount, 1 as sort_col from receipt $where2)
as a order by  sort_col desc
?>
```

Any body give any solution for these issue?

Comment: clarify what u want for which condition?

Comment: With these query,when i give sale_type in where condition,i got the matched fields of sale table and all fields from receipt table,I want only the matched the fields from sale table ,no data from receipt table.

Comment: might be easier if you show columns and contents of both tables. I'm totally lost here....

Comment: You can use join to achieve this, please eloborate it.

Answer (score 0):

The `FROM` part of your query has to be parametrized in function of the tables you need.
You have to do something like this:

```
<?php
$where='where 1';
$where2='where 1';
if ($sale_type<>'' && $deposited_type<>'') {
    $where.=" and sale.sale_type='$sale_type'";
    $where2.=" and receipt.deposited_type='$deposited_type'";
    $tables = "sales INNER JOIN receipt ON sales.cust_id. = receipt.cust_id"
} 
else if($sale_type<>'') {
    $where.=" and sale.sale_type='$sale_type'";
    $tables = "sales"
}
else if($deposited_type<>'') {
  $where2.=" and receipt.deposited_type='$deposited_type'";
  $tables = "receipt"
 }
```

and then you build your query with:

```
SELECT ...
FROM $tables
WHERE conditions with $where and $where2
```

Beware of SQL injections with conditions like `receipt.deposited_type='$deposited_type'`

Answer (score 0):

I think your database structure is wrong, if the customer made a more than one 
sale the query will generate a duplicate result

Please create a database structure like below

```
    sale(id,total,sale_type,cust_id)
    receipt(id,net_mount,payment_type,sale_id)
```

In the above table you can put sale_id in receipt table instead of cust_id

so the query will be

```
 select sale.total,receipt.net_amount,receipt.payment_type from sale INNER JOIN 
 receipt ON sale.id=receipt.sale_id where sale.sale_type='credit'
```

You can easily generate above query in php. Please let me for further clarification.